# TikZ: Can a node be placed at pos = .5 and then a coordinate at the end of the line?

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

As the title say, can a node and a coordinate be placed on the same line?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (P1) at (-2, 0);
  \coordinate (P2) at (2, 0);
  \draw (P1) -- (P2);
  \draw[-latex] (P1) -- ++(-88.2036:1.75cm) node[scale = .75, pos = .5,
  fill = white, shape = circle, inner sep = 0cm] {\(\nu_2\)};
  \draw[-latex](P1) -- ++(-20:5cm) node[scale = .75, pos= .5,
  fill = white, inner sep = 0cm, shape = circle] {\(v_2 = 12.9005\)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Can I add a coordinate to end of `(P1) -- ++(-88.2036:1.75cm)`?  I couldn't find anything with a search or in the manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a coordinate directly after the node or directly before it.

### Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (P1) at (-2, 0);
  \coordinate (P2) at (2, 0);
  \draw (P1) -- (P2);
  \draw[-latex] (P1) -- ++(-88.2036:1.75cm)
     node[scale = .75, pos = .5, fill = white, shape = circle, inner sep = 0cm] {\(\nu_2\)}
     coordinate (here);
  \draw[-latex] (P1) -- ++(-20:5cm)
     coordinate (there)
     node[scale = .75, pos= .5, fill = white, inner sep = 0cm, shape = circle] {\(v_2 = 12.9005\)};
  \draw[blue] (here) -- (there);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]